# How can i connect to an excel as data source using PHP

Tags: php

I have the below code but it always returns

> "FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected 'is' (T_STRING), expecting ','
>   or ')' on line number 6"

there are no hidden characters, is there anything that I missed?

```
 <?php
    $excelFile = realpath('C:\Users\pc09758\Desktop\Complete Web Developer Codes\1.html\My Project\YUMS\YUMS.xlsx');
    $excelDir = dirname($excelFile);
    $connection = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xlsx)};DriverId=790;Dbq=$excelFile;DefaultDir=$excelDir" , '', '');
    $sql = "SELECT A, B, C FROM Sheet1";
    $results = odbc_exec($connectionString, $sqlQuery);
    while(odbc_fetch_row($results))
    { 
        $output1 = odbc_result($results, 1); 
        $output2 = odbc_result($results, 2); 
        $output3 = odbc_result($results, 3); 
    }

    print(“Excel Data”); 

    print("$output1 ");  

    print("$output2 "); 

    print("$output3 ");

    print(“”);

    odbc_close($connectionString);
?>
```

Comment: Where does `$sqlQuery` comes from? I think it should be `$sql`

Comment: Use `""` instead of `“”`

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/ please use this this is better

Comment: Thanks David Angulo.

Comment: tnx @DavidAngulo. i followed your suggestions and still has some errors:

Comment: realpath() has been disabled for security reasons on line num 2
odbc_connect(): SQL error: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect on line num 4       Undefined variable: connectionString on line num 6
odbc_exec() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given on line num 6
odbc_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given on line num 7
Undef var: output1 on line number 8
Undef var: connectionString on line num 9
odbc_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given on line num 9